# React jsx Order of execution: <button> inside <a>

Tags: reactjs, jsx

Imagine I have the below code：

```
<a href="URL">
    <button onCLick={this.doSomething}>do something</button>
<a>
```

If I click on the button, do I go to `URL` first or do I execute `doSomething` first?

In my experience, it goes to URL first. What if I want `doSomething` to execute first, then go to `URL` after `doSomthing` is done?

Appreciate your help ^_^!

Comment: There are better ways to do this.  Are you using React Router in your app?

Comment: @squillman Yes! I use <Link> then replace it by <a>. I think they are similar, but <a> refreshes the page while <Link> does not. Is that true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The handler will run first. This is why you can prevent the page from redirecting by calling `preventDefault` on the event - if the handler run *after* the page started redirecting, prevention of redirection wouldn't be possible:

```js
const App = () => {
  const doSomething = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('doing something');
  };
  return (
    <a href="https://example.com">
        <button onClick={doSomething}>do something</button>
    </a>
  );
};
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class="react"></div>
```

If you want to wait until `doSomething` is done, it sounds like it's asynchronous - call `preventDefault` on the event, like above, then assign to `window.location.href` when the function finishes.

```js
const App = () => {
  const doSomething = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { href } = e.target.parentElement
    console.log('doing something');
    setTimeout(() => {
      window.location.href = href;
    }, 2000);
  };
  return (
    <a href="https://example.com">
        <button onClick={doSomething}>do something</button>
    </a>
  );
};
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class="react"></div>
```